# JSTL Session Hash Map containing Objects - How to print Objects

Tags: java, jsp, session, object, hash

I have a Servlet that gathers form data, makes a database query, retrieves the data, and puts it into a Hash Map. Such as below:

ResultSet rs = d.execute(SQL);

```
        // Get session and and create hash map (fhMap is flight-hash-map)
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        HashMap<Long, UserFlightsBean> fhMap = new HashMap<Long, UserFlightsBean>();

        while(rs.next()) {
            int FlightNumber = rs.getInt("FlightNumber");
            String Operator = rs.getString("Operator");
            String Source = rs.getString("Source");
            String DepartureTime = rs.getString("DepartureTime");
            String Destination = rs.getString("Destination");
            String ArrivalTime = rs.getString("ArrivalTime");
            int Cost = rs.getInt("Cost");
            int Seats = rs.getInt("SeatsAvailable");

            // Get session, get UserFlightsBean, set session UserFlightsBean
            UserFlightsBean ufb = new UserFlightsBean(FlightNumber, Operator, Source, DepartureTime, Destination, ArrivalTime, Cost, Seats);
            fhMap.put((long) FlightNumber, ufb);

            System.out.println(FlightNumber + "\t" + Operator + "\t" + Source + "\t" + DepartureTime + "\t" + Destination + "\t" + ArrivalTime + "\t" + Cost + "\t" + Seats + "\t");
        }

        // Add hash map "fhMap" to session bean
        session.setAttribute("fhMap", fhMap);
```

As you can see, I create an object with the query, each row from the database is an object which I put into the hash map, then I add the hash map to the session so that I can access it on my jsp page.

On the jsp page I get the session hash map and now I'm trying to print out the elements of the objects, and this is where my problem lies. My code for the jsp page is below:

```
    <%
        HashMap <Long, UserFlightsBean> printMap = (HashMap <Long, UserFlightsBean>)session.getAttribute("fhMap");
        pageContext.setAttribute("objects", printMap);
    %>

    <c:forEach items="${objects}" var="entry">
        Key is ${entry.key} <%-- these two for testing purposes --%>
        value = ${entry.value}<br>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="junk" items="${value.UserFlightsBean}">
                <li>${junk.getFlightNumber()}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </c:forEach>
```

So what I'm trying to do is print (into a `<li>`) all the variables that are contained in that object. I've searched everywhere online, scowered the Stack Overflow waters, and cannot find out how to do this.

Thanks for any help one may provide!

Comment: `items="${value.UserFlightsBean}">` should be `items="${entry.value.UserFlightsBean}`.

Comment: I think some of the answers on right side "related" section will help you. Have you looked at them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here , what i can understand, you need not to use inner loop...
You can write code like this:

```
`<c:forEach items="${objects}" var="entry">
        Key is ${entry.key} <%-- these two for testing purposes --%>
        <ul>
            <li>${entry.value.getFlightNumber()}</li>
            <li>${entry.value.getOperator()}</li>
            <li>${entry.value.getSource()}</li>

        </ul>
</c:forEach>`
```

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it exactly. I removed the extra <c:forEach> loop inside, then changed printed values to entry.value.getMethod() and it worked great! Thanks for your help!